# matlab, format table nicely, without cell arrays

Tags: matlab, formatting

Asking because I suspect there's an easy way I'm unaware of and couldn't google to satisfaction:
I want to format a cell array nicely and a table would be very convenient. How can I format the strings contained in a cell array to be formatted nicely without any `'` and `{''}` pre/suffixes?

```
t={'a','b','c'}
cell2table(t,'VariableNames',{'1','2','3'})

ans =

  1×3 table

      1        2        3  
    _____    _____    _____

    {'a'}    {'b'}    {'c'}
```

Comment: By "formatted nicely" you mean when printed in the Command Window? Would you be happy if this *wasn't* a table, but you still got rid of the quotes and braces? How big is your cell array?

Comment: Each table entry contains a cell that contains a character vector. Character vectors are defined and shown with single-quote symbols. Displaying for example the first entry of the table as `{a}` would make no sense; what would `a` be there?

Comment: @Wolfie the table seemed like a quick and easy go-to, it does not need to be a table. The data can be e.g. considered as a cell array where the first row is the column names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hear ya. I don't like seeing those quotes either.

If you don't care about performance, you can just convert all the strings to categoricals for the purpose of display.

```matlab
t = {'a','b','c'};
tbl = cell2table(t,'VariableNames',{'1','2','3'});
tbl_for_display = varfun(@(x) categorical(x), tbl)
```

Produces:

```
tbl_for_display =
  1×3 table
    Fun_1    Fun_2    Fun_3
    _____    _____    _____
      a        b        c
```

Here's the cleaner way to do it, with a helper function:

```matlab
function out = nice_table_for_display(tbl)
out = tbl;
for i = 1:width(tbl)
  if iscellstr(tbl{:,i}) || isstring(tbl{:,i})
    out.(out.Properties.VariableNames{i}) = categorical(tbl{:,i});
  end
end
end
```

So you do:

```
>> nice_table_for_display(tbl)
ans =
  1×3 table
    1    2    3
    _    _    _
    a    b    c
```

Or, if that's no good, you need to go all the way and write your own custom replacement for `table.disp`.

Comment: I have never had to use varfun yet, this works great. It's a minor thing but in a workflow with some people, this makes a difference

Comment: FWIW, `varfun(@(x) categorical(x), tbl)` could be shortened to `varfun(@categorical, tbl)`

Answer (score 0):

You can't get rid of `''` or `""`, but you can use strings instead of character vectors for a better formatted table display:

```
>> t = {"a","b","c"}

t =
  1×3 cell array
   {["a"]}    {["b"]}    {["c"]}

>> cell2table(t,'VariableNames',{'1','2','3'})

ans =
  1×3 table

     1      2      3 
    ___    ___    ___

    "a"    "b"    "c"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andrew and others, here's a *slightly* insane 'oneliner' / anonymous function.

It works by converting all table contents to categorical, then reassembling the table from that categorical array.

```matlab
disp_table = @(tbl) disp(array2table(categorical(cellfun(@(x) num2str(x),table2cell(tbl),'uni',0)),'VariableNames',tbl.Properties.VariableNames));

%test the display function, create table...
tbl = cell2table({'a','b','c',NaN,-1,{'asdf asdf'}},'VariableNames',{'1','2','3','4','5','6'});
disp_table(tbl)

    1    2    3     4     5         6    
    _    _    _    ___    __    _________

    a    b    c    NaN    -1    asdf asdf
```